# How to re-use a capturing group to match a different alternation choice?

Tags: regex, backreference, capturing-group

I have a group of words and another group with a conjunction. I’m looking for a regular expression that matches any single one of those words, demanding the conjunction in between:

- If the words are `(A|B|C)`
- and the conjunction is `(&)`
- then do match `A & C`, `C & B` and even `A & A`
- but don’t match `A + C`, `A C` or `A & D`

---

**Practical example:** Consider this platform-agnostic regex: `/(Huey|Dewey|Louie) and \1/`.

I want it to match “Huey and Louie” or “Dewey and Huey”, but it only matches “Huey and Huey”, because backreferences merely match previously *matched* texts.

I could repeat myself by using `/(Huey|Dewey|Louie) and (Huey|Dewey|Louie)/` but I think there’s a smarter way of re-using capturing groups at a later time. Is that feasible somehow?

Comment: @rock321987: Let me hope you’re afraid for no reason just a short while longer. Anyway, putting the words group in a variable accounts for the DRY issue 

Comment: i think you have an answer now by @melpomene if recursion is supported by programming language you are using..

Comment: @rock321987: Too bad you deleted your comment.

Comment: well that comment won't make sense now, when its answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this if you're using Perl (or a language with sufficiently compatible regexes):

```
/(Huey|Dewey|Louie) and (?1)/
```

The `(?N)` part is a "recursive subpattern", matching the same thing as the subregex in capturing group `N`. (The difference between this and backreferences like `\N` is that `\N` matches the same *string* that was matched by the capturing group. `(?N)` reuses the regex itself.)

Comment: Uhh, recursive subpattern, me likey! This was obviously conceived for this purpose, and it’s clean and short. Even though it might be considered exotic, it seems to be supported by a decent [number of regex engines](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html#engines).

Comment: @SWLim: I know [what to do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when someone answers. Do you? Because this *isn’t* the right solution for *me*, but it’s a good and correct answer. Still, it’s only fair to wait at least half a day for some more attention.

Comment: @dakab You have a good point, thank you for pointing that out. Sorry I have assumed from your comment that this answer is the right solution and that you might have forgotten to accept the answer.